# In the beginning vrs at the beginning and In the end vrs at the end

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm having a hard time finding an Italian equivalent to theses phrases.
**At the beginning** means at the place or time at which something starts.
eg. ***There is a contents page at the beginning of the book.

  **In the beginning, means initially and implies further change.

eg. ***I thought that the Italian language was difficult in the beginning, but now I think it’s easy***.
  **At the end** means at the last part or further part of something.
eg.  ***You will find a revision test at the end of the book.***
 **In the end**  means finally, at last, when having taken everything into consideration.
eg.  ***I had decided to go to his house but in the end, I went back home instead.***
What are the equivalent phrases in Italian, showing exactly the difference in their  meanings??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning = "[all'inizio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inizio_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)" 
eg.

> *L'indice (the contents page) è all'inizio del libro*

for the second example you can use "[inizialmente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inizialmente_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)" that means initially or still use "all'inizio"

> "All'inizio/Inizialmente pensavo che l'italiano fosse difficile, ma
>   ora penso che sia facile"

Similar to at the end = "[alla fine](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fine2/)"

> "Troverai la revisione alla fine del libro"

Another use could be "[infine](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/infine_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)" but I personally use "alla fine" more often.